# Get sticky posts from database using $wpdb class

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to use a custom query to get specific post info from the database if the posts are sticky.

Here is the query:

```
"SELECT ID, post_title, post_author, post_date, option_value
FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}posts`, `{$wpdb->prefix}options`
WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'
AND option_name = 'sticky_posts' 
ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 2"
```

But this query does not work. It returns two posts but not the sticky ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured it out.

I needed to use this code and check for id with `AND ID IN ($stringSticky)`:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );         
$stringSticky = implode(",", $sticky);

$mostLatestPostsSticky = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT ID, post_title, post_author, post_date
    FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}posts`
    WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'
    AND ID IN ($stringSticky)  
    ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $postlimit"
);
```